# SyntaxError: missing ; before statement / Expected ';' and instead saw '['

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

This is part of my code that decomposes a sentence into word values of an array:

```
//var sentence = document.forms["chatForm"]["chat"].value;
var sentence = ";Hey, this is a sentence!"; //Example
var preMsg,msg = sentence.toLowerCase().match(/[\w'-;]+/g);
var msg[0] = msg[0].replace(/^;/, '');
if (msg[0] !== preMsg[0]) { //Checks if semi-colon was removed
    msg.unshift("hooray");
    alert(msg[0]+" "+msg[1]); //Testing
}
```

What I get from JSLint:

Expected ';' and instead saw '['.

```
var msg[0] = msg[0].replace(/^;/, '');
```

The console gives me this error for the same line of code: SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

I'm just beginning to learn JavaScript, and I don't know what is wrong with that line.

Comment: `preMsg` is always `undefined` in your code. `var preMsg,msg = 42;` doesn't mean both variables will have value 42.

Comment: @zerkms Is there a way to do something like that? Or do I just have to do "var preMsg = msg"?

Comment: `[\w'-;]` probably doesn't do what you expect. It will match word character, or any ASCII character *between* apostrophe (x27) and semicolon (x3B), which includes commas and periods.

Comment: @p.s.w.g I'm fairly sure it does. It wasn't outputting semi-colons until I added that to the list.

Comment: @Dimitto: yep, just another explicit assignment

Comment: @Dimitto I simply mean `[\w'-;]` is not the same as `[\w';-]` because hyphen behaves differently when it appears in the middle of a characters than when it appears at the beginning or end. See [Character Classes or Character Sets](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) for more information.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Thanks for that, regex is very confusing to me.

I tested it out with http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ and it started matching other characters like you said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want just `msg[0] = ...`

`var` is for declaring variables!

Answer (score 4):

`[` is not a valid character for a variable name, and the line

```
var msg[0] = msg[0].replace(/^;/, '');
```

is declaring a *new* variable named "msg[0]", you just need to remove `var` and change it to:

```
msg[0] = msg[0].replace(/^;/, '');
```